# Send multiple parameters with the same name in post request

Tags: python, html, python-requests, http-post

trying to log in to this site using python https://sis.yu.edu.jo/pls/yuapps/f?p=134:101:165660500709862:::::

have noticed (by ysing BurpSuite) that there is multiple parameters to be sent with the same name but different values (the "p_arg_names" parameter have 4 different -constant- values)

> data ={'p_flow_id':'134','p_flow_step_id':'101','p_instance':qw.attrs['value'],'p_page_submission_id':div.attrs['value'],'p_request':'LOGIN','p_arg_names':'3808843104802386083','p_t01':'%D9%8A%D8%B..etc','p_arg_names':'1235407356725963','p_t02':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yu.edu.jo','p_arg_names':'174514341787584706','p_t03':'username','p_arg_names':'174514439646584711','p_t04':'gggg','p_md5_checksum':''

How can I send them with POST request? Simply putting them throws "404 Not Found Error"

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the key "name" would be better to contain an array as it's value, instead of having a number of keys e.g. `p_arg_names`. It doesn't make much sense the same object or "thing" to have two names, or two of the same properties that are in conflict.

So, better way is to do this:

```
{
  "p_arg_names" : [ "3808843104802386083", "1235407356725963", "..." ]
}
```